# Change one of the array value if it equals to something

Tags: php

I'm using `explode()` php function to divide the sentence and turn it into array the user had filled in the input field on different page. From that sentence I need to find if there is that word and if it is in it add `<b></b>` around of that word. I've tried:

```
$wordsentence = explode(' ', $wordsentence);
$place == '0';
foreach ($wordsentence as $ws) {
    if ($ws == $word) {
        $word = '&lt;b&gt;'.$word.'&lt;/b&gt;';
        $save = $place;
    }
$place++;
}
```

but there might be more than one word in the same sentence. Is there any way to mark multiple words?

Comment: $word = '&lt;b&gt;'.$word.'&lt;/b&gt;'; supposed to be $word = '<b>'.$word.'</b>';

Comment: What is your target output here? since what you're doing right now is just overriding `$word`. Your declaration of `$place` is also wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initial setup:

```
$wordSentence = "This is a sentence, made up of words";
$wordTest = "made";
$wordsArr = explode(' ', $wordSentence);
```

I swapped out the foreach loop for a standard for loop, this way we don't need to initialize a separate index variable and keep track of it.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($wordsArr); $i++) {
    if ($wordsArr[$i] == $wordTest) {
        $boldWord = '<b>' . $wordTest . '</b>';
        //take your wordsArray, at the current index,
        //swap out the old version with the bold version
        array_splice($wordsArr, $i, 1, $boldWord);
    }
}
```

And to complete our test:

```
$boldedSentence = implode(' ', $wordsArr);
echo $boldedSentence . "\n";
```

Output:

`> This is a sentence, <b>made</b> up of words`

Comment: Happy to help! If that wraps up your question, please accept the answer. Otherwise I would be happy to assist further.